# Substance Painter: Face selection Mask

Tags: masking

Is there a possiblilty to select the polygons of the model that the brush will apply to? This is what happens when I paint the insides of a house.

Inside:
[image]

Outside:
[image]

As if the absence of WASD Camera controls wasn't bad enough, every brush stroke smears up faces around it. Painting indoor environments is a pain in Substance Painter but I don't see any other program that can do the job.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the poligons you don't want to paint, and after you do everything make them visible again?

Comment: I had no idea how to do that so I did some research and found something better (nicolas answer) http://steamcommunity.com/app/273390/discussions/0/558749824859717048/

Comment: pressing I will invert the selection

Comment: if you found a solution, answer the question and mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to Quick Masking Mode by pressing T on your keyboard. Then Select the area that you want to mask out. Masked areas will be colored black. Invert the selection by pressing I on your keyboard.

[image]

Press T again to apply the mask and begin painting. T will toggle between paint mode and mask mode so you can go back and forth as you need.

[image]

Once you're finished press Y on your keyboard and the mask will be removed and lost forever.

[image]